# Prevent iOS SImulator to move to active desktop?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I found this is annoying.

I always put my iOS simulator in different Desktop with Xcode's. I notice that since I updated my Xcode from 6.x to 7.0.1 (I didn't update to 7.0), whenever I run iOS simulator from Xcode, it always moves to my current active window.

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the OS your working with (Yosemite, El Capitan) you can assign applications to the spaces/desktops you wish. Just launch the simulator on the desktop you wish it to maintain, and <kbd>^</kbd>+Click the icon and select 'Options' and then a contextual menu will populate for you to elect the display you wish to it to maintain. This works for dual displays as well. This is more of  'sticky' fix as opposed to a dynamic workflow solution, which you may be after, but it gets the job done in a free, efficient manner.

Comment: I never know there is a feature in Options that can stick the app in certain desktop. Thanks!